# How to installation PhoneGap with os x mavericks for the first time

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap. I bought a new Mac Mini with OSX Mavericks and I want install PhoneGap in it. I installed it in Mountain Lion, and it worked, but in Mavericks, it's not showing PhoneGap template in Xcode. Can someone please help me to install it properly on Mavericks.

Thanks To @Sport and @iDev, I have installed PhoneGap successfully but while creating an application it says `missing library phonegap/www/3.3.0` and `started downloading https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/3.3.0.tar.gz...`

Can you please help me, why is happening? Did I miss something?

Comment: what problem you are facing

Comment: @iDev I'm Unable see Phonegap template in xcode. i did Once i use this line in terminal $ sudo npm install -g phone gap it is asking for password i entered system password then it generates this line 'npm http GET registry.npmjs.org/phonegap'for 3 times and nothing happens

Comment: there not show in xcode. the advanced version not implemented like the only phoneGap 1.5 only in available xcode template

Comment: if i want to create new project using phone gap how can i.

Comment: only in phonegap/cordova 1.5  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html

Comment: i have update my question please have a look at it once

Comment: i tried it earlier adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/  here i don't get Cordova-1.5.0.pkg in download file it is auto installed and show uninstall script file in zip folder

Comment: set proxy setting in your node.js

Comment: @iDev thanks i set the proxy now and it give new error please see my question for the error i updated over there

Comment: do you install your own system/Mac  or organization system

Comment: my organization. any issue with it(i mean security is blocking the commands).

Comment: i guessed your answer check my new answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phoneGap uses NodeJS to do it's thing. You can [download NodeJS here](http://nodejs.org/download/), for OSX Mavericks I used the Installer (.pkg) and the process was quite painless.

Ensure you can run the command npm -l before proceeding.

[Getting Started with PhoneGap on OSX Mavericks - iOS](http://tylermauthe.com/2013/11/09/phonegap-ios-osx-mavericks.html)

[how-to-get-phonegap-working-on-mac-os-x-mavericks](http://adamwadeharris.com/how-to-get-phonegap-working-on-mac-os-x-mavericks/)

Edit: For your error solution. node config proxy server

```
npm config set proxy http://server:port
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Comment: after hitting above statements i gave npm install -g phone gap I got same error

Comment: Nice solution than boss

Answer (score 1):

just use this step on 
step 1: go to [here](http://nodejs.org) and download and instal node.js.

step 2: run this command on terminal

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

the`n $ phonegap`  run this 
 you will get result like this

```
Usage: phonegap [options] [commands]

Description:

  PhoneGap command-line tool.

Commands:

  create <path>        create a phonegap project
  build <platform>     build a specific platform
  install <platform>   install a specific platform
  run <platform>       build and install a specific platform
  local [command]      development on local system
  remote [command]     development in cloud with phonegap/build
  platform [command]   update a platform version
  plugin [command]     add, remove, and list plugins
  help [command]       output usage information
  version              output version number

Options:

  -V, --verbose        allow verbose output
  -v, --version        output version number
  -h, --help           output usage information

Platforms:

  keyword            | local environment   | remote environment
  -------------------|---------------------|-------------------
  android            | Yes                 | Yes
  blackberry         | Yes (BlackBerry 10) | Yes (BlackBerry 6)
  ios                | Yes                 | Yes
  symbian            | No                  | Yes
  webos              | No                  | Yes
  wp7                | Yes                 | Yes
  wp8                | Yes                 | Coming Soon

Examples:

  $ phonegap help create
  $ phonegap help remote build
  $ phonegap create path/to/my-app
  $ phonegap remote build android
```

means phone gap in installed in your system

final step

```
phonegap create your-app
```

cd your-app

Comment: @Charan Giri let me know if any problem

Comment: Once i use this line in terminal $ sudo npm install -g phone gap it is asking for password i entered system password then it generates this line 'npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap'for 3 times and nothing happens

Comment: yes just wait 2 ,3 mint when terminal  process completed then type phone gap

Comment: i have update my question please have a look at it once.

Comment: type node in terminal ,what is the result commit here

Comment: > is the result i got by typing node in terminal

Comment: npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz >run this then install phone gap or cordova @ Grili let me know what is error coming

Comment: yes i have seen but try 
npm install registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz

Comment: Response is : addLocal Could not install registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

Answer (score 0):

Working behind a corporate firewall so had to add config changes for the proxy
(`proxy = http://@ngproxy.northgatevehiclehire.net/`)
This is probably an issue with your proxy setting.

If you want to use a username/password please use `http://username:password@yourproxyhost:port` - if you don't have a username password, please you have to remove the '@'.

Comment: i typed like this is this correct $ npm config set proxy http://@ngproxy.northgatevehiclehire.net/

Comment: ngproxy.company.com:prot_no

Comment: npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Comment: this link understand for u http://superuser.com/questions/347476/how-to-install-npm-behind-authentication-proxy-on-windows

Comment: i followed your previous answer i got installed but responses are different. when i am trying to create project it say www file missing and downloading ... timeout and stops. is this okay or am i missing some this. thank for your help buddy

Comment: sure... can you help me with why it is saying www file missing and downloading code is phone gap create mygapApplication

Comment: it is said from comment line

Comment: yes, i typed phonegap create appname  response id www file missing and downloading from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/3.3.0.tar.gz and timed out . in that folder there is no application folder(i mean missing)

Comment: Some issue with proxy how to fix it